# I am recieving a php notice after an successful upload or cancellation

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have a table where it appends rows and that I have 3 rows, the table below will look something like this:

```
  Question No     Image

    1            (file input)
    2            (file input)
    3            (file input)
```

Below is the code that creates the table above:

```
var qnum = 1;  
var numimage = 0;

var $qid = $("<td class='qid'></td>").text(qnum);
var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 


          $('.num_questions').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);

     var $questionNumber = $("<input type='hidden' class='num_questionsRow'>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());

     $qid.append($questionNumber);  
    ++qnum;
    ++numimage;          
    $(".questionNum").text(qnum);
    $(".numimage").val(numimage);

});

    var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" + numimage + "' />" +
    "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" +
    "<input type='reset' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>" +
    "</p><p class='listImage' align='left'></p>" +      
    "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");        

    $image.append($fileImage);

   $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($image);
```

The problem I have is that if a file was unsuccessful or cancelled and then I upload another file which is this time successful, I recieve this notice below in my iframe:

```
Notice: Undefined index: numimage in /web/stud/...../app/imageupload.php on line 150
```

My question is that why do I recieve this notice in my php code below where it inserts data into database when I successfully upload a file after an unsuccessful attempt or cancellation?

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

 $lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;         

 $imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId)  
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 

     if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) { 
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
       echo "Prepare statement err imagequestion"; 
    } 

$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage'];

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("isi",$lastID, $sessid, $qnum); 

$sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : ''); 

    $insertimagequestion->execute(); 

                if ($insertimagequestion->errno) { 
          // Handle query error here 
        } 

        $insertimagequestion->close(); 

      }

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

UPDATE:

Below is the jquery code where it contains the `startimageupload` function for when uploading starts and the `stopimageupload` function for when uploading stops or is finished:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

$(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
$(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
$(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

$(".sbtnimage").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$(".sbtnvideo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$(".sbtnaudio").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

$('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
$("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
return stopImageUpload(2);
});

return true;

}

var imagecounter = 0;
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){
var result = '';
imagecounter++;

if (success == 1){
result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span><br/><br/>';
$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
}

else if (success == 2){

result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was canceled</span><br/><br/>';

}

else {

result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span><br/><br/>';
}

$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" class="fileImage" type="file"/></label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label><label><input type="button" name="imageClear" class="imageClear" value="Clear File"/></label>');
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');

$(".sbtnimage").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".sbtnvideo").removeAttr("disabled");
$(".sbtnaudio").removeAttr("disabled");

$(".imageClear").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parents("form:first").find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");
});
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the notice isn't being triggered by the failed upload? It seems to me that to cancel your upload you are just rewriting the iframe that you're using to send the image up... this could end up with all sorts of unexpected errors at the server side... I'm not sure if php will execute a script with a half complete file upload or not, it's not something I've ever checked. You may also find with some clients that they request your upload URL twice - first to request headers (sending no data) and second to post the file data.. this can confuse if you aren't expecting it.

Comment: @pebbl Well what I tested is that if I cancel a file upload, and then cancel another file upload, I recieve no notice. But when I then upload a successful file, then the notice appears. Same happens if I have 2 unsuccessful file uploads and then have a successful file upload

Comment: Ok, and you don't get this message when just starting with successful uploads?

Comment: @pebbl I do not recieve this notice after a successful upload in first attempt or even successful uploads back to back. It is only when I have an unssucessful upload or cancelled an upload that then the next successful file upload will recieve this notice

Comment: Ok, well with the code you've shown there isn't anything that would say as to why you aren't getting `numimage` at the php-side *(as you have this as a hidden field in your form)*.. However you have omitted code from the `startImageUpload` function, so it's difficult to tell exactly how you are triggering each of you uploads.. plus it's difficult to see how you are managing the setting of your form in the iframe with each upload request. Do you have a live example? or can you flesh out the source code a bit more?

Comment: @pebbl Do you want me to display the code for starting and finishing upload from the view source script? Is there any other code you wish to view?

Comment: @pebbl I have include full jquery code on how image files are uploaded and finished in the question below where it says `UPDATE` This cose is from the view source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from looking at the code you've posted I'm making a guess as to what is happening because I can't see the complete flow of the code. Basically the following code is causing your problem:

```
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');
/// THIS LINE BELOW
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').html(result + '<label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" class="fileImage" type="file"/></label><br/><br/><label><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label><label><input type="button" name="imageClear" class="imageClear" value="Clear File"/></label>');
/// THIS LINE ABOVE
$(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');
```

The above code is taken from the code that runs after a succesful/errorful upload has occured. This code proceeds to overwrite the form responsible for uploading the image. Now this is fine for successes because as I can infer, your interface uses seperate forms for each image... once you get a success you don't reuse that form again *(so no error on the server side for subsequent uploads)*.

However, when the image upload errors or cancels... I think I'm guessing right - that you try and reuse that form to upload the image again? If so you have overwritten and removed the numimage input html:

```
<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='2' />
```

Which means that you would get an error as this field doesn't exist anymore.

Again as I say this is a guess, but it would lead to the removal of a field that did exist to start with, and would produce the problems you are seeing.

Comment: I will say you are correct because in the hidden input, the value is suppose to be the question number associated with the file input. Now the correct number does appear when a file is successful with no previous problems. But when the file is unsuccessful/cancelled then I upload a successful file. then the value it inserts in the db states '0'. So I would say you definelty correct, this is what is happening. My only question to you now is do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That would be a second question ;) urm well if it were me I just wouldn't overwrite the form with anything *(especially on error)*. Instead insert an error message above or below the form and then temporarily hide the form *(like you are doing with other elements)*. Then when you come to reuse the form just make it visible again and remove the error / cancelled message. That way your form content is always going to be the same...

Answer (score 1):

It can't find the key numimage within the $_POST array - this implies that numimage is not being sent by your ajax call. Have you tried using Firebug to look at what is being sent to the php script?

Comment: I am using google chrome to test this. I will quickly test it in firefox and see what firebug says :)

Comment: Chrome has network tab as well, please see your browser's documentation for developer tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: It is ok, I have tested it in firefox but I don't recieve any info in the firebug. It is the `Console` section which sees what is being sent to php script

Answer (score 0):

line `$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage'];` is causing it. $_POST array doesn't seem to set the value for index `numimage`

Comment: Do you have any ideas what I need to manipulate in the code so that it sets a value for numimage in this situation?

Comment: the submission of the form needs to be done after you append the form `$image.append($fileImage);`. check to see if the form has all the values by inspecting it using developer tools.

Comment: So are you saying more the image form after `$image.append($fileImage);`?